# java.lang.StringBuffer java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, groovy, jvm

I am getting below error while reading data from database. 
please provide your thought about the cause.
note - I have increased maximum heap size.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:45)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.<init>(StringBuffer.java:79)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPool.enforceMinimum(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPool.doMaintenance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPoolGroup.doMaintenance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPoolMaintenance.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPool.enforceMinimum(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPool.doMaintenance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPoolGroup.doMaintenance(Unknown Source)
    at com.ddtek.pool.ConnectionPoolMaintenance.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:97)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:251)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:117)
```

Comment: There might be some memory leak.

Comment: There ia no generic solution for this type of problem, you can try increase the heap (`-Xmx1024m`) but your best bet would be to actually investigate the dump with external tools to track down the memory leak

Comment: yes I have -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use eclipse mat tool to get what causing you memory leak, as follows 
1- use  java visualvm to run your application for sometimes and in the early time get heap dumb, keep running it for around one or 2 hour and get other heap dumb, finally configure you visualvm to get your hep dumb on  OOM situation. 
2- use MAT tool (it is eclipse Memory analysis tool) and analyze all of your heaps dumb, for sure you will be able to get the root cause, but this is one of the hardest task in java.